# How to redirect to component with previous created task

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image]

[image]

I have component where create task (first pic). If task create success then I need to redirect to another component with that created task (second pic). Give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `react-navigation`? If yes, you can do this:

`navigation.navigate('ComponentName', { task })`

And then, in the `ComponentName` component:

```
const ComponentName = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  /* 2. Get the param */
  const { task } = route.params;
```

See doc [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

Comment: No, I am using react router

Comment: Are you saving the created task in a back-end or something? If so, you can try this, passing only the id and using the id to get it from the back-end:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component

Comment: Yes, I send the task to the back-end. So how I guess which id 
assigned for this task on the back-end?

Comment: When you call the endpoint to create the task, the success response should return it to you.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out.